# Biblatex style=authoryear causes warning

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

Adding biblatex the option `style=authoryear` causes [writeLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/) to give the warning message

```
Package biblatex Warning: Please rerun LaTeX.
(biblatex)                Page breaks have changed.
```

I do not get the warning when I run locally on AUCTeX.

Comment: That is a warning, no error, informing you that latex needs an extra run. I am not sure, if writelatex can handle biber now, or has the newest version of biblatex available.

Comment: I have edited my question accordingly. I had a similar version of the document running on [writeLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/) recently, then I edited it locally for a few weeks and re-uploaded. During these two weeks I updated my texlive distribution from 2009 to TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2012/Debian).

Comment: From [writeLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/)

_"Our biblatex support is still a bit experimental, and it looks like we're not running LaTeX quite enough times, as the warning says. We'll be upgrading TeX Live and upgrading our build system, which should fix this problem. Until then, I'd recommend using the default style. Also note that the problem may go away as you edit the document, because it has to do with how LaTeX breaks your document pages, which may change as you add or remove content -- it's just a warning, so it won't prevent your document from compiling."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

writeLaTeX have now updated their Tex live distribution. I no longer have this problem. They notified this morning.